# Linear regresssion on body mass index

Tags: normal-distribution, outliers, nonlinear-regression

I am using a continuous variable of body mass index. I checked the distribution using statistical tests and determined it is not normally distributed. I think these results are driven by outliers, there is a huge number of them. How can I deal with outliers? I am going to use this variable as a dependent variable for a linear regression.

Comment: Relevant discussions here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86835/normality-assumption-in-linear-regression https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163642/what-to-do-if-residuals-are-not-normally-distributed

Comment: BMI is useless. Do you have a measure of waist circumference instead? BMI is no longer a risk factor for metabolic syndrome after adjusting for waist circumference while waist circumference remains a risk factor.

Answer (score 0):

First, BMI is a really terrible measure.

Second, nothing in OLS regression requires that the DV be normal.  The errors are assumed to be normal.  However, outliers may be a problem but this can be dealt with by using e.g. quantile regression.

Comment: It's interesting Pearson rejected BMI = weight / height^3 (thus BMI as a weight-density) in favor of weight / height^2 because it made *his* data look more normal. He failed to project what modern agriculture would do to waistlines.

Comment: I am using a multiple linear regression for gender age and ethnicity as independent variables and one of the assumptions is normality of data. If i was using a logistic regression it wouldnt be an issue i think. What am asking is possible paths that i can use.

Comment: No, normality of the data is not an assumption of linear regression.That is incorrect.

Comment: Ok thanks. i thought that normal distribution is related to standard error mean which for my bmi variable is 0.091. Is that acceptable?

Comment: It's impossible to say whether that is acceptable.